# Implement a search algorithm on Matlab

Tags: matlab, search

Example

a={'hello' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'Sam'}

b={'and' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'Susan'}

- **Search from a**

Is 'hello' in a? Yes, so output 1

Is 'my' is a?    Yes, so output 1

..
..

Is 'Sam' in a?   Yes, so output 1

so we get 
**

- matrix1=[1 1 1 1 1]

**

Then, look through the words in a and b to b

Is 'Hello' in b?   No, output 0
Is 'my'' in b?     Yes, output 1

...

Is 'Sam' in b?   No, output 0

Is 'and' in b?     Yes, output 1

Is 'my' in b?      Yes, but ignore as 'my' already exists.

... all the way to 'susan'.

And we get this

**

- Matrix2=[0 1 1 1 0 1 1]

**, which reads 'hello' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'Sam' 'and' 'Susan', so it has stored all words from both sentences.

I need to do this for a number of matrices, all different dimension, here's what I have so far:

```
    for i=1:length(a)
           for j=1:length(a)
           if isequal(a{i}, a{j})
             a{i}=1;
           else
            a{j}=0;
           end
           end
    end
```

This doesn't return [1 1 1 1 1 ], and I don't know what do 
do from here.

Comment: Have you had a look at ismember? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html

Comment: Who's Kevin? :)

Your example is not consistent, however check my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been using two different examples for this algorithm, I've edited it now, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I've tried to use ismember @Dan . It works, but I don't know how to ignore words that appear more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use MATLAB's [unique()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), then I would go about it like that:

```m
a = {'hello' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'Sam'};
b = {'and' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'Susan'};

% Combine the two inputs
c = [a,b];

% Get unique strings without sorting and retaining first occurrence in posC
[unC, posC] = unique(c);

% Create logical tf and check true in positions determined by posC
tf       = false(size(c));
tf(posC) = true;

% Check result
c(tf)
ans = 
    'hello'    'my'    'name'    'is'    'Sam'    'and'    'Susan'
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error with your code, with unique           ??? Error using ==> cell.unique at
29
Unrecognized option.   And I'm trying to have a matrix which starts with a, then has a,b, and if I had a matrix c, I'd have another matrix with the words from a,b,c respectively. I'm trying to implement this algorithm for a number of matrices. So would I do d=[a,b,c], and continue as you did?

Comment: I removed the `'stable'` option in the call to `unique()` and you shouldn't be getting the error anymore.

The brief answer is yes. However, if you have control on how `a,b,c,d...` are created I would store them inside a cell array: `out = {a, b, c, d...}` and then simply concatenate with `out = cat(2,out{:})`.

Comment: tf = false(size(c)); gives out an error as well. It seems that it uses subsindex, which does not work with cells. I have to read sentences from a script, and convert them to matrices. I don't even know how many matrices I get, it's well over 200 matrices. If I'm able to implement this for two matrices, I should be able to do the rest. Thank you for your swift replies :)

Comment: I'm using the code you posted above, only using matrices a and b, and I get this error after creating tf                                   
        >> tf = false(size(c));
??? Error using ==> subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not
defined for values of class
'cell'.

Comment: You probably have a variable called `size` in the workspace which is shadowing the function `size()`.
You can check with `which size -all`, look at the first line.

Comment: Is there any way for it to be sorted, as the output I get at the end isn't Hello my name is Sam and Susan, it's not ordered

Comment: It depends how you concatenate `a` and `b`. To be more precise on my comment I would need to see how you actually implement your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000868/word-search-algorithm-using-an-m-file   That's the link to my new question, I thought it would be easier this way.