# Word search algorithm using an m.file

Tags: algorithm, matlab, wordsearch

I have already implemented my algorithm using cells of multiple strings on Matlab, but I can't seem to do it through reading a file.

On Matlab, I create cells of strings for each line, let's call them line.

So I get

```
     line= 'string1' 'string2' etc
     line= 'string 5' 'string7'...
     line=...
```

and so on. I have over 100s of lines to read.

What I'm trying to do is compare the words from to the first line to itself. 
Then combine the first and second line, and compare the words in the second line to the combined cell. I accumulate each cell I read and compare with the last cell read.

Here is my code on

for each line= a,b,c,d,...

```
for(i=1:length(a))
for(j=1:length(a))
  AA=ismember(a,a)
  end

  combine=[a,b]
  [unC,i]=unique(combine, 'first')
  sorted=combine(sort(i))

  for(i=1:length(sorted))
for(j=1:length(b))
  AB=ismember(sorted,b)
 end
 end

 combine1=[a,b,c]
```

.....
When I read my file, I create a while loop which reads the whole script until the end, so how I can I implement my algorithm if all my cells of strings have the same name?

```
    while~feof(fid)
    out=fgetl(fid)
    if isempty(out)||strncmp(out, '%', 1)||~ischar(out)
    continue
    end
    line=regexp(line, ' ', 'split')
```

Comment: It sounds to me that you could read in the whole file, then just call a unique. However, the file might be irregular and that could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data file is called `data.txt` and its content is:

```m
string1 string2 string3 string4
string2 string3 
string4 string5 string6
```

A very easy way to retain only the first unique occurrence is:

```m
% Parse everything in one go
fid = fopen('C:\Users\ok1011\Desktop\data.txt');
out = textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);

unique(out{1})
ans = 
    'string1'
    'string2'
    'string3'
    'string4'
    'string5'
    'string6'
```

As already mentioned, this approach might not work if:

- your data file has irregularities
- you actually need the comparison indices

**EDIT: solution for performance**

```m
% Parse in bulk and split (assuming you don't know maximum 
%number of strings in a line, otherwise you can use textscan alone)

fid = fopen('C:\Users\ok1011\Desktop\data.txt');
out = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
out = regexp(out{1},' ','split');
fclose(fid);

% Preallocate unique comb
comb = unique([out{:}]); % you might need to remove empty strings from here

% preallocate idx
m   = size(out,1);
idx = false(m,size(comb,2));

% Loop for number of lines (rows)
for ii = 1:m
    idx(ii,:) = ismember(comb,out{ii});
end
```

Note that the resulting `idx` is:

```m
idx =
     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

The advantage of keeping it in this form is that you save on space with respect to a cell array (which imposes 112 bytes of overhead per cell). You can also store it as a sparse array to potentially improve on storage costs.

Another thing to note, is that even if the logical array is longer than the e.g. double array which is indexing, as long as the exceeding elements are false you can still use it (and by construction of the above problem, idx satisfies this requirement). 
An example to clarify:

```m
A = 1:3;
A([true false true false false])
```

Comment: I have to compare each index of a line, with say the combination of that one to the ones above. So I need to be able to implement the code I wrote above while reading a file. All matrices differ in the number of words it has, but I am just going to give all matrices the length of the longest matrix.                                                              I need each string to stay in the correct order, as in the end I have to compare the sentences to see the similarities in words.  And each line should have a matrix of logical value if the word in that line appears in the combined matrix

Comment: ans=[1 1 1 1] for first line, ans=[0 1 1 0] for second line, ans=[0 0 0 1 1 1] for last line, so I have line1 compared with line1, then line2 compared with line1+ line 2, then line3 compared with line1+line2+line3 etc, I hope this clears things up

Comment: Ok, I would still import in bulk but preserving the positioning. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: This is so great, it works exactly as I intended it, you have been a lot of help Oleg, I really appreciate this! One last question, is there a function on Matlab which lets you ignore spaces, because I have a lot of that in my script. .... And I'm trying to use ismember('hello', out) to only see the matrices with 'hello' in them, but it doesn't work for me.   I tried creating a for loop for out, and if ismember(hello, out{i}) to print these but that's wrong

Comment: Do you mean that you have something like e.g. `out{1} = {'hi','this','','was','empty','this',' ','was','space'}`?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I have a lot of spaces between some words, 'hi' '' '' '' '' '' '' 'this' 'was' 'empty'

Comment: Right after creating `comb`, you can efficiently remove empty cells with `comb = comb(~cellfun('isempty',comb));`.

Comment: Cheers, works perfect. In your code, you create a matrix for the combination, but not for each line, so how can I look to see whether  a word is in a matrix and output just those matrices with the word in them?

Comment: You can use [`strcmpi()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) or [`strcmp()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html). Compare a string against a cell array of strings.

Comment: I've got for(i=1:3)     if strcmpi('hello', out{i,1}) , and it shows me all matrices, with 1 in the index where there is hello. What do I do to display only the idx with the word 'hello'